# Lumen throws 500 sometimes when sending API request?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, lumen

I am developing an application using `anuglarJs` on client side and `Lumen` in server side for REST API's.  My `.env` configuration given below,

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=TRUE
APP_KEY=XrPbyRlU5p0szSw5MrAQWwWim8C0MXjT

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=kainfo
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

And enabled  `Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');` in bootstrap/app.php

My problem is,sometimes `Lumen` throws 500 exception and working well on next refresh request.
[image: lumen]

The Error log is ,

```
[2015-06-06 07:51:41] lumen.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Study\kasrodinfo\web\vendor\illuminate\database\Connectors\Connector.php:47
```

Comment: See the error log in the server to know the exact issue.

Comment: @Blip I have updated question with error log

Comment: From the error it seems that you are trying to connect to database `forge` with a blank username and no password in your file *Connector.php* and the connection is getting denied by the mysql server. Recheck the connection - correct username, password, database name etc. If you don't find errors or are confused then post the *Connector.php* with the requisite problem details.

Comment: Thank you for comment,When I put database credintional directly in database settings file,it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the database,username,password in \vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\config\database.php file

Answer (score 0):

Also affected by this, here is what we have found on this issue:

We were using Apache 2.4 with the Event MPM and a thread-safe build of PHP 7. This caused the env() method to not respond reliably - it could give you the right variable at one point in the code, then just a few rows down it would return something else. (Like the default variable which trevorg was experiencing.)

We switched to using the prefork MPM and the problems vanished instantly.

Yes, prefork sucks in terms of speed when compared to another MPM, but it seems there is some issue with the event MPM and environmental variables in Apache, PHP and/or Laravel/Lumen.