# laravel / lumen REST API intermittently ingores env and uses 'forge' database

Tags: rest, laravel-5, lumen

There seems to be a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30680282/32763).

I have a js frontend talking to a lumen REST API.

My frontend can end up doing a lot of requests per second to the same endpoint.

Let's say `api/supplier/<ID>`

Most of these return successfully but approximately 5%-10% of the time the API returns an error like:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1
>   PDOException in Connector.php line 50:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forge'

This indicates that the wrong database configuration is being used somehow.

The only place in the code where I can find the string `'forge'` (including quotes) is in
`...\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\config\database.php`

However from the relevant mysql section there it looks like a username 'forge' would also be set if this is used, and my .env is being ignored.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE','+00:00'),
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

I get no error if I request them directly from a browser.

The problem seems to be related to the frequency of requests, more requests/sec = more errors.
The errors will be on different items if I reload the page.

If I overwrite the /vendor/.../config/database.php above with my values (database/username/pwd/prefix) then I don't get any errors, but this is hardly the correct way and makes me suspect a bug somewhere.

Environment:

- Windows 8
- XAMPP 5.6.8 with PHP 5.6.8
- Mysql 5.6.24
- Lumen 5.1.3 (Laravel Compnents 5.1.*)

My questions are

1. Where is this 'forge' database name coming from intermittently?
2. How do I get my real database details in there all the time?
3. Should I be somehow pooling my connections, seeing as there might be hundreds of connections/sec or does laravel/lumen already take care of this?

Comment: did you ever figure out the actual problem? the accepted answer is a hack.

Comment: not really. It only happens on my dev machine (xampp), which also has a problem with missing memcache, even though it's configured not to use it (may or may not be related). The production server (lamp) doesn't have these problems iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overwriting the file database.php within the framework you can create a config directory on the root of your project and there database.php create a file which you can modify the way you want. Lumen understood that you want to use your own configuration file and not the one that brings the default framework.

Check if uncomment this line in the bootstrap/app.php

```
Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
```

Comment: That's the problem. I have defined my database connection details in the .env file in the root but it doesn't seem to be applied every time. Your solution works well though. Do you think it's a bug in lumen? If noone can answer my other questions I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: I not think it's a mistake to Lumen. Now on second thought, you have uncommented this line

Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');

In the bootstra/app.php

Comment: the line was uncommented all along. So it wasn't that. But creating the file in the config directory worked well.

Comment: duplicating the config files in config directory still doesn't work (Lumen 5.5), still values need to be hardcoded in config files it env() still doesn't work sometimes (happens much frequently). Any workaround?